# Fastest way to return a list of records depending on many many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-5, query-performance

I'm developing an API in Rails in which exists `users` and `messages` tables. Also `users` have a gender (`gender_id`), belong to a country (`country_id`) and also have a civil status (`civil_status_id`) and the `messages` are created by `admins`.

So up to here I have this model.

[image]

**Now I have to develop the following requirement**

> An admin should be able to create a message targeted to `users` depending on its attributes (country, gender or civil status). Also, the admin should be able to declare a message as a global message, in this case "all" `users` should receive it, but exceptions should also be allowed. For example, in the case where an admin want to send a message to users from all countries, except people from Russia and China.

The thing is I'm no Rails/SQL expert, but I want to make this efficiently so that if tomorrow the app has ten thousand or a hundred thousand users the server responds quickly.

**So I was thinking the following**

First create 3 many-to-many relationships (`countries_messages`, `genders_messages` and `civil_statuses_messages`). The record of these tables represent the relations between the `messages` and the `countries`, `civil_statuses` and `genders`.

Then create a form where an admin can create a message, where by means of several select boxes, he should be able to choose the attributes of the users to whom he wants to reach. The form for creating a message should also have a checkbox to determine if the message is global, if its marked then I would consider that the selected countries, genders and civil statuses would be the categories that the administrator wants to exclude, i.e. if an admin want to send a message to all the people in the system except for people who are from Canada he should mark the global option and select the country Canada in the select box (obviously this would be stated in the view).

Now up to here I have this model.

[image]

In what I do have doubts is which way is more efficient to return the messages that corresponds to a user.

#### Method 1

When an admin specifies that a message is global, except for those from country with id 3 then I could add to `countries_messages` records like (country_id: 1, message_id: 2), (country_id: 2, message_id: 2), (country_id: 4, message_id: 2), ..., etc. i.e. forming a relation with every country except the country with id 2.

Then retriveng the messages that the current user should read like the following:

```
global_messages = Message.where(global: true).ids

country_messages = current_user.country.messages.ids
gender_messages = current_user.gender.messages.ids
civil_status_messages = current_user.current_status.messages.ids

@messages = Message.find(global_messages + country_messages + gender_messages + civil_status_messages)
```

#### Method 2

Other way could be forming a relation of that message with the excluded country, i.e. if I make a message exclusively for people from country with id 2 then I should add the record (country_id: 2, message_id: 2) in `countries_messages`, but in the contrary case if I made a message to every country except the country with id 2 then I should also add the record (country_id: 2, message_id: 2) to `countries_messages`.

In this case I can know if a message is excluded for males and people from Argentina, for example, if the message is global AND it's associated with the country and gender record that represents Argentina and males.

Then the retriveng of the messages that the current user should read would be like this:

```
global_messages = Message.where(global: true).ids

country_messages = current_user.country.messages
gender_messages = current_user.gender.messages
civil_status_messages = current_user.current_status.messages

excluded_country_messages_ids = country_messages.where(global: true).ids
excluded_gender_messages_ids = gender_messages.where(global: true).ids
excluded_civil_status_messages_ids = civil_status_messages.where(global: true).ids

@messages = Message.find(global_messages + country_messages + gender_messages + civil_status_messages - excluded_country_messages_ids - excluded_gender_messages_ids - excluded_civil_status_messages_ids)
```

There could be more ways to do the same, so I want to receive recommendations or if you see that I could make improvements to do the same then tell me. If there is something you do not understand ask.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database choice, you may want to consider storing the message "attributes" (country, gender, ...) in a jsonb column on your messages table.  It could also include a `user_ids` attribute to simplify things.  The queries might look a little funny, but you can move a lot into scopes to clear things up in your code and even add indexes to speed things up.

[Here is a great article on using jsonb with indexes in Rails with postgresql](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/).

Another alternative you could do is make a `UserMessage` join table with a polymorphic reference that could associate the different attributes to a message and user:

```
class UserMessage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :messageable_type # e.g. "Country"
  belongs_to :messageable_id # e.g. some Country id
end
```